# How to package and deploy Grails 3.3.2 Angular project in tomcat

Tags: angularjs, grails

I created sample Grails Angular project. When I run a `gradlew war` it packages only server-side code, its not adding the client-side code.  What is the proper way to package and deploy this project?

```
./gradlew war
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
:server:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:server:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:server:buildProperties UP-TO-DATE
:server:processResources
:server:classes
:server:compileGsonViews
:server:war

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 17.307 secs
```

Comment: Is the 'grails war' not working?

Comment: its working its create package only for server side code, didn't include client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit of having separate projects (client/server) is the ability to deploy them separately. If you want to deploy them together, then they should be in the same project. See this guide on how to merge them together.

http://guides.grails.org/angular2-combined/guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks James, I will package angular2 separately.